# Struts2 Form in parts

Tags: struts2

I was wondering if I can do this in struts 2:

```
<h4>Select Category</44>
<s:form id="Step01Page" action="Step01Page">
    <s:select name="nombreCategoria" list="categorias" 
        listKey="nombre" listValue="nombre" label="Categorias"
        headerKey="Crear" headerValue="Crear Nueva"/>
</s:form>
<h4>Name of Category</h4>
<s:form id="Step01Page" action="Step01Page">
    <s:textfield label="Nombre de la Categoria"/>
</s:form>

<sx:submit formId="Step01Page" value="Siguiente" cssStyle="float:right;"/>
```

I'm doing the DOJO plugin ofr Struts 2.

Comment: describing problem in details will be much good thing and will help you to get good answers

Comment: Please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that breaking up the form in that way would work.  Since Struts by default formats the form in a table, you can insert lines into the table in the middle of your form like so:

```
<s:form id="Step01Page" action="Step01Page">
    <s:select name="nombreCategoria" list="categorias" 
        listKey="nombre" listValue="nombre" label="Categorias"
        headerKey="Crear" headerValue="Crear Nueva"/>
</s:form>

<tr><td colspan="2"><h4>Name of Category</h4></td></tr>

<s:form id="Step01Page" action="Step01Page">
    <s:textfield label="Nombre de la Categoria"/>
</s:form>
```